# How long does it take for Delta to process EU261 compensation requests?

Tags: air-travel, compensation, delta-air-lines, ec261

My connection from the EU to Seattle via JFK on Delta was delayed today due to the first flight being late and I’ll arrive to my destination 12 hours late, which definitely entitles me to a 600 EUR compensation. How long does Delta generally take to pay out such requests?

**Updated:** still nothing as of Oct 18th. I've thus filed a dispute with the Czech aviation authority.

Comment: In my experience, no airline will pay without dragging their feet first. They will likely ignore your claim until you escalate.

Comment: @Hilmar oh, I'll definitely escalate, just wanted to know when to do so.

Comment: Not sure if anyone actually has enough relevant data at this point (apart from Delta). In my experience (intra-EU, not Delta), these things used to take weeks to a few months pre-pandemic, and then that suddenly turned into a year and a half. No idea how much things have settled down by now.

Comment: @TooTea I still see companies use the "in these difficult times" excuse, so I won't be surprised if it takes a long time!

Comment: [Does the regulation on the EU261 flight compensation set any deadline for airlines to pay the compensation?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/81095/31)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my case it took **5.5 months** to receive compensation, though I suspect it would've taken much longer if I didn't contact the Czech Aviation Authority after waiting for a reply for 4 months. So I would recommend anyone in the same situation to file a dispute with Delta, wait for two months, then file a dispute with the aviation authority located in the country of the flight's departure.