# What's Delta's official contact email/website for EC261 compensation?

Tags: delta-air-lines, ec261

5 weeks ago I've had a delayed flight from the EU via JFK, which caused me to miss my domestic connection, thus making me entitled for 600 euros of compensation under EU261. After arriving home I immediately filed a support request on Delta.com describing the situation and received an email with a case number and the following text:

> We apologize that our current response times may exceed 30 days in some instances.

Well, now its been over 30 days and I still haven't heard back. Is there a different email/contact I can use to request the 600 Euros? I'm trying to exhaust their official channels before I resort to filing a case with one of the EU261 compensation brokers.

Comment: I've heard (from other travel sites) that a public tweet to Delta (or other airlines) about the issue will usually prompt a response.

Comment: @Midavalo It's sad that a lot of customer service is only resolved these days by what is effectively public shaming by the loudest voice.

Comment: Can't you use the email address that the case number was sent from?  And if not, does that email contain any other contact details?  In general when I've had a case from automated system, the replying to that email address updates my case notes.

Comment: Most airlines route E-mails about EU261 directly to the trash bin. You need to be a very squeaky wheel.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/174300/how-long-does-it-take-for-delta-to-process-eu261-compensation-requests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use their "comment and complaint" form:

https://www.delta.com/eu/en/need-help/overview?commentComplaintsForm

Sources:

1. This is what Delta links to from their official EU 261/2004 information page, https://www.delta.com/eu/en/change-cancel/exit-eu-compensation
2. Delta's "Request a Refund or Reimbursement" form says: "For residents of countries other than the U.S. and Canada, or for flights departing from an airport within the European Union, please submit requests through our Comment and Complaint form."

So, use that form and you should be good to go.

Update: I received compensation 16 days after filing a claim this way. I hope this gives some hope to people filing a claim. I was initially offered $651.71 (€611 at time of receipt, so a favorable exchange rate) via a wire transfer. I replied asking for €800 of travel credit instead, per their policy. They replied within an hour with an $868.95 eCredit (€815). I hope this helps!

Comment: You will also need to file a dispute with the local aviation authority 30 days after submitting a complaint, as Delta has no intention whatsoever of making a payout on their own: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/177196/how-long-does-it-take-for-the-czech-aviation-authority-to-reply-to-eu261-compens?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thanks for sharing this tidbit. After your comment, I was ready to do that. It seems delta has maybe improved their process around this since last year.