# How long does it take for the Czech Aviation Authority to reply to EU261 compensation disputes?

Tags: czech-republic, ec261

After 4 months of waiting for [Delta to respond](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/174300/how-long-does-it-take-for-delta-to-process-eu261-compensation-requests) to my compensation request, I've filed a dispute with the [Czech Aviation Authority](https://www.caa.cz/en/). How long should I expect until I receive a reply?

Comment: In some cases, depending on the country of your residence, you may find the small claims court (or equivalent) or an appropriate alternative dispute resolution body for consumer contracts more helpful than national civil aviation authorities (who may lack power to compel the airlines over a particular consumer dispute, but do compile statistics that can influence future policy making).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case it took **43 days** to receive a response confirming that they've contacted the airline, haven't received a reply for 14 days and will now escalate the matter further. Less than 24 hours after that [Delta agreed](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/174300/how-long-does-it-take-for-delta-to-process-eu261-compensation-requests?noredirect=1&lq=1) to pay out the full 600 Euros in compensation.

So I presume it takes ~1 month for the Czech Aviation Authority to start processing your complaint.