# El Al flight changed at airport due to short layover at Ben Gurion - liability for compensation/refund?

Tags: el-al

I had a flight booked from Madrid airport to Bucharest(OTP) via Tel Aviv with El Al.

The first leg was scheduled to land at 0430, with the second leg taking off at 0700.

On arrival at Madrid I was informed that this was not permissable as the minimum layover time at Ben Gurion is three hours. Both flights were booked as a single booking though the El Al website.

I was offered a later flight from Tel Aviv, but that would be an 11 hour delay and would mean I missed the meetings I had scheduled in Bucharest - which was the whole reasons for taking the overnight flight. Therefore I refused the offer and left the airport.

As El Al sold me flights that they then could not fulfil I would expect to get a full refund of the ticket price. Is this correct?

Also, (and this is where it gets a bit more complicated), this was part of a larger trip. LHR -> Madrid -> OTP (via Tel Aviv) -> London. As a result of this I had to find a hotel for the night in Madrid and then arrange a flight back to London the following day and also cancel my scheduled flight from Bucharest to London. Are El Al liable for these costs as well?

I'll be putting all this in writing to El Al, but would appreciate any insight into their liability here.

Thanks!

EDIT: El Al have agreed to refund the flight and pay €600 compensation. Alls well that ends well.

Comment: How did you book those flights on their site? I suppose you used a multi-city search? What airports and dates did you enter? If you entered the MAD-TLV and TLV-OTP yourself (rather than stating you wanted a MAD-OTP flight and they returned the flights via TLV) then they are considered independent legs (like outbound and return flights) and they do not check MCT since they consider it’s not a connection.

Comment: Strangely enough Google Flights suggests the El Al flight combination, but the El Al website does not seem to allow it.

Comment: It was booked as a multi-city flight. I think Skyscanner suggested the option and I think booked it direct. It was all under a single booking reference.

Comment: @pauljwilliams Your last comment is not clear to me. Who sold you the ticket? Skyscanner or El Al?

Comment: El Al, via their website. I take the point about this being two flights versus a connection, but they were clearly aware that there was a problem - because when I arrived at checkin the agent said 'Ah, you're the Bucharest passenger' - so they'd clearly realised the issue.

Comment: You need to be very precise how exactly this was booked A) `LHR->MAD->TLV->OTP` or as B) `LHR->MAD->OTP `? If you booked as A) then you are probably out of luck.

Comment: While you apparently can’t find connecting flights on the El Al site, you can find that flight combination on third party OTAs, and you can find it on the El Al site when coming from Skyscanner. It would be good to see how this was booked (indeed the four flights at once or just MAD-TLV-OTP, and whether MAD-TLV-OTP were considered connecting or not). If sold as connecting then EC261 applies, but it’s difficult to find which box you fit in (delay at departure, at arrival, denied boarding, cancelled flight…) which will determine which rights apply (refund, rerouting, return, compensation…).

Comment: By googling, I find conflicting information about minimum transit time. Are you sure it was not for some special reasons?

Comment: The LHR->MAD and OTP-> LHR were booked totally separately via BA. The only flights on this booking were MAD->TLV and TLV->OTP

Comment: @pauljwilliams: the question is still relevant: did you book this a  multi-city MAD->TLV & TLV->OTP or as a single one way MAD->OTP ?

Comment: It was shown as a connecting flight on Skyscanner. When I went to the EL Al website to book then the only way to proceed was as a multicity booking, which was what i did.

Comment: Questioner here - El Al have agreed to refund the flight and pay €600 compensation. Alls well that ends well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the itinerary is weird to me, and El Al apparently wouldn’t suggest it if you searched for it directly on their site, when you come from Skyscanner as you did it seems to be sold as a regular connecting flight with a 2h30 layover in TLV.

As such, the flight should be covered by EC261.

It’s difficult to be certain, but I would suppose this would qualify for a cancelled flight. The EU’s [Air passenger rights website](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm) says:

> Cancellation occurs when:
>
> - your original flight schedule is abandoned and you are transferred to another scheduled flight
>
> (…)

Note that case law tells us that a series of connecting flights is considered like a single flight from origin to final destination, so while neither individual flight was cancelled or rescheduled, the fact that they wanted to change your second flight should be equivalent to a change is schedule.

In this case, you would be entitled to:

- your choice of refund, rerouting, or return. Since you were at the origin, no return possible. They suggested an alternative (rerouting), but you didn’t take it, so you should be able to get a refund (probably would have been better if you said so at the airport but I don’t think this changes anything)
- since you were informed less than 14 days before departure, unless they can prove they notified you in time, compensation of 400 euros.

You can’t claim for the OTP-LON flight, and since you didn’t take a re-routing option which would have required it, not for the hotel either. All your costs are considered covered by the 400 € fixed amount.

Of course, there are chances they will claim extraordinary circumstances, but the case would be quite flimsy.

Still, expect them to refuse all of it or part of it for whatever reasons, and for the whole process to last a while. Stand your ground and reiterate what you are owed. In some cases it’s easier to use one of the companies which does all that for you (and have the lawyers to push it), but they’ll of course take a good chunk of it.

Good luck!

Comment: Thankyou. I will proceed as you suggested. This has been super helpful!

Comment: 'All your costs are considered covered ..' is wrong. The EU regulation only sets a minimum baseline for compensations and explicitely does not exclude further claims (article 12. 1). If the airline actually sold a flight ticket, which violates the airline's own transfer rules and therefore cannot be fulfilled under any conditions, I would consider that gross negligence and not generally rule out the possibility to get recovery for further damages based on  civil liability and not just on the EU passenger rights regulation.

Answer (score 2):

To add to @jcaron's great answer, here's how I would file for EU261 compensation based on [a prior experience](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/174300/how-long-does-it-take-for-delta-to-process-eu261-compensation-requests).

1. File a request with El Al requesting compensation
2. Most likely they'll stonewall you or outright deny compensation, which is fine
3. Once it's been a month since filing a dispute with El Al (or immediately after they deny you compensation), file a dispute with the [Spanish Aviation Agency](https://www.seguridadaerea.gob.es/en/ambitos/derechos-de-los-pasajeros/procedimiento-para-reclamar/procedimiento-para-reclamar-ante-aesa-reg.261-2004) (AESA), attaching all the evidence that you have. No need to involve intermediary companies such as AirHelp, as they follow the exact same process.
4. Most like the AESA will rule in your favor and El Al will pay you 400 EUR for your trouble. Note that the airline is not liable for your hotel room or your flight back to London, as per the current rules.

Comment: AESA has no binding authority on airlines in terms of compensation. They can say "EL AL didn't provide compelling argument to deny compensation and we think you're eligible to it". but El Al has no obligation to follow that recommendation. the next step is seeking legal action.

Comment: @meego interesting… but in my experience it worked like a charm with Delta.

Comment: @meego My guess is the airline knows that you're serious when you file a dispute with the authority, and having a ruling from AESA in your favor would make it much more difficult for the airline to win in court if you decided to pursue it further.