EC261 with multiple connections
I had a single ticket booking from Manchester > Dubai > Melbourne > Auckland on the shortest connecting flights.
Emirates operated the first 2 flights, Qantas the last.
A technical issue with the plane in Melbourne caused me to arrive at my final destination >3hrs later than schedule.
Can I claim UK/EC261 compensation for this based on the Wegener v Royal Air Maroc ruling?
(Single journey delayed at final destination from a flight leg entirely outside EU, originating in a member state with two or more connecting flights.)
If so, is the claim made to Emirates (who I booked with) or Qantas (the operator of the delayed leg)?
Thanks


Can I claim UK/EC261 compensation for this based on the Wegener v Royal Air Maroc ruling?

Yes. According to most interpretations you are entitled to compensation.
See https://ukairpassengerrights.co.uk/regulation-ec261-vs-uk261/

If so, is the claim made to Emirates (who I booked with) or Qantas (the operator of the delayed leg)?

Qantas. The current rulings are quite clear that the "operating carrier" is on the hook.
However, don't expect Qantas to roll over easily. Like many airlines they will  most likely ignore your claim initially, than try to brush you off to Emirates, than claim "extraordinary circumstances" and than drag their feet for many months. You will have to be persistent, engage a 3rd party collector (for a fee) and research potential escalation paths.
The good news here is that Qantas does operate a flight in the UK so they have some experience with this and there is potential leverage through a complaint to a UK oversight agency.

And as a last resort, use one of the companies offering to deal with the airline in exchange for a share of the compensation: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/185058/do-the-ec261-compensation-companies-actually-do-anything-other-than-filing-a-com
